# Which word should I use for "nickname"?

Tags: word-choice

I found many candidates in ReVo: alnomo, alinomo, kaŝnomo, kromnomo, karesnomo. I doubt they are all synonyms. In which situations should I use each one?

I'd like to find the one to use when presenting oneself. For example "Hi, my name is Robert, but my nickname is Bob". Or when someone has a really long name, I might want to ask "Do you have a nickname"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Kromnomo* - nickname

*Kaŝnomo* - alias, pen name; a fake name to hide your real name

*Karesnomo* - a familiar name (for friends only)

So, if you're asking someone with a long or difficult name if you can call them something else, it would be *kromnomo* -- unless you want to call him "honey" or "Billy Buttons."

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Tomaso Alexander's excellent answer, I would like to remark that *alinome* is the most popular translation of English *aka*, e.g. “Miguel Gutiérrez Adúriz, *alinome* Liven Dek”. It gets ~96000 google hits, while *kromnome* gets ~900. OTOH, the nouns *alinomo* and *kromnomo* get similar google hit numbers, and in the particular case of an author's pen name, *plumnomo* is the most popular choice, even if the other alternatives are possible and actually used.

Comment: For sure there are many ways to say a.k.a. - ankaŭ nomate, pseŭdonime, eĉ "ps.".

Answer (score 2):

Related words:

**Moknomo** - sobriquet (referring to ridiculous nature, unflattering, teasing, mocking) nickname

**Pseŭdonimo** - Kaŝnomo de verkisto aŭ artisto

**Alnomo** -  alias, nickname